# Establishing VPN connection sets NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI to false?

Tags: android, networking

As the old way of detecting wifi connection (*getNetworkInfo*) is deprecated in android, I am trying to migrate my app to the latest way, below is what I have for now (in Kotlin):

```
fun isWifiConnected(context: Context): Boolean {
    val cm = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager?
    cm?.activeNetwork?.let { network ->
        cm.getNetworkCapabilities(network)?.let { capability ->
            return capability.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

It works well until I get vpn connected (on my samsung s8 + shadowsocks), the *capability* in above code no longer has *TRANSPORT_WIFI* transport, but *TRANSPORT_VPN* instead. And if I connect vpn without wifi then get wifi connected, *isWifiConnected* returns *true* again (*capability* has both *TRANSPORT_WIFI* and *TRANSPORT_VPN* in this case).

It seems that the previous transport capabilities would all be reset to false when vpn connection gets established, which sounds like a bug to me, why having one new capability needs to reset old capabilities?

I was hoping this is just a bug of my vpn app (shadowsocks) but I tested same cases on my pixel 2 + shadowsocks, which works quite fine, *isWifiConnected* returns *true* as long as wifi is connected, no matter having vpn or not.

So this is a Samsung bug?

Comment: have you had any answer / workaround ? I have the same issue on my side. The above code can't detect the presence of wifi when using VPN over wifi.

Comment: @PaulW, yes, I now use WifiManager instead of ConnectivityManager. See the posted answer below as sample.

Answer (score 1):

The solution works well so far:

```
fun isWifiEnabled(context: Context): Boolean {
    val wm = context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager?
    return wm?.isWifiEnabled ?: false
}
```